# Use Hibernate with Oracle and Esri St_geometry type

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, oracle-spatial, st-geometry, hibernate-spatial

Can anyone tell me whether I could use Hibernate with esri ST_GEOMETRY type? 
I have found that Hibernate Spatial does support SDO_Geometry, but nothing for ST_Geometry.

I am using oracle 11g and arcgis 10.2

Comment: Did you got any feedback on this? Would also be interested on this functionality.

Comment: Nothing so far. I decided to use native queries @Schuller Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got something working.

It's still beta, but first test are very promising.

I'm working with the WKT/WKB representation to store it in the database.

It looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dau_track")
public class DauTrack {

    @Column(columnDefinition = "st_geometry")
    @Type(type = "lu.schuller.arcgisStGeometry.WkbStGeometryType")
    @ColumnTransformer(read = "st_asbinary(shape)", write = "st_geomfromwkb(?,2169)")
    private Polyline shape;
```

I created my own Wkb-HibernateType to convert the wkb-data betweent database and geometry-api. I have already implemented JTS and esri-geomeotry as geo-libraries.

The 'columnTransformers' are modifiing the generated hibernate-sql to read and write under wkb-form in the database.

It's currently running under postgresql, but will it also use under Oracle.

If I had some time, I will publish it on github.

Comment: Just created an bitbucket project with all sources: http://bitbucket.schuller.lu/hibernateSTgeometry

Comment: It's an old thread, but the links are dead. Any update? I'm literally about to write this very thing. Edit: looks like this link works: https://bitbucket.org/tomlux/hibernatestgeometry

Comment: yes, this is the correct link: https://bitbucket.org/tomlux/hibernatestgeometry